# Simple PHP OOP and MySQLI

Tags: php, oop

I am trying to learn some more PHP, OOP and MySQLI, but I am stuck. Google didn't help me and searching on this website didn't give me any results either. I have a config class to connect to the database, and in another class I want to run some queries, but I am getting this error with whatever I am trying:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in
>   test.php on line 9

Can someone please help me?

config.php:

```
<?php

class Database
{
    private $host;
    private $user;
    private $password;
    private $db;
    private $mysqli;


    function __construct() {

        $this->host     = "private";
        $this->user     = "private";
        $this->pass     = "private";
        $this->data     = "private";

        $this->mysqli   = new mysqli($this->host, $this->user, $this->pass, $this->data);
    }


    public function query($query)
    {
        return $this->mysqli->query($query);
    }
}
?>
```

test.php:

```
<?php
class Dummy
{
    private $Database;

        function __construct()
    {
        $this->Database = new Database();
        $this->Database->test = $this->mysqli->query("SELECT test FROM test")->fetch_object()->test;
        }
}
?>
```

index.php:

```
<?php

require 'config.php';
require 'test.php';

$test = new Database();
$test = new Dummy();

echo $this->Database->test;
?>
```

Comment: What/Where is `gw2Database` ?

Comment: check out that line. look at the thing you call `query` on -> it is a  `mysqli` object in the current (`Dummy`) class. But there is nothing that's called that. so it doesn't exist.

Comment: Learn from [this repo](http://github.com/simon-eq/pdowrapper) because, I think you are doing it wrong, if you are hardcodding your queries inside your class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about using Dependency injection, create the Database object then pass that as a parameter to the class through the construct.

```
<?php
class Database
{
    private $host;
    private $user;
    private $password;
    private $db;
    private $mysqli;


    function __construct($host,$user,$pass,$data) {

        $this->host     = $host;
        $this->user     = $user;
        $this->pass     = $pass;
        $this->data     = $data;
        $this->mysqli   = new mysqli($this->host, $this->user, $this->pass, $this->data);
    }

    public function query($query)
    {
        return $this->mysqli->query($query);
    }
}
?>
```

...

```
<?php
class Dummy
{

    function __construct(Database $db)
    {
        $this->db = $db;
    }

    function get_test_yada(){
        return $this->db->mysqli->query("SELECT test FROM test")->fetch_object()->test;
    }
}
?>
```

...

```
<?php 
$db    = new Database('127.0.0.1','root','pass','database');
$dummy = new Dummy($db);


$dummy->get_test_yada();
?>
```

Untested, hope it helps

Comment: fyi, switching to PDO will enable you to build a `Database` superclass that can do any type of database, then you can pass which db type you want to the class through the construct, then your Dummy model wont care about the specifics of Database just that it has Database..

Answer (score 1):

For the goodness sake, DON'T learn them all at once. You won't get any sensible result.

Each is a hard and complex topic alone, of which OOP is hardest.

For the database interacton use **PDO prepared statements.**

As the OOP practice, never extend class from a service, but use it as a class variable.

```
class Dummy
{
    protected $db;

    function __construct($pdo)
    {
        $this->db = $pdo;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->mysqli   = new mysqli($this->host, $this->user, $this->pass, $this->data);
```

If connecting fails, you can't call anything on that member variable. Check if your connection is established first.

And, if you want to have access to that variable, you should make it public.